# Passing parameters from checkboxes with jQuery and ajax() method

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get some entries in a JSON Response from
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
by selecting checkboxes with jQuery and the ajax() method.

I can see with Chrome DevTools that 2 requests are made, one of type "Document" and one of type "XHR". For The first the response is correct but for the second there is no response. This is how they look like:

Request URL: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId%5B%5D=3&userId%5B%5D=4
with Query String Parameters:
userId[]: 3
userId[]: 4

Request URL: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=3&userId=4
with Query String Parameters:
userId: 3
userId: 4

and this how my HTML and JavaScript and jQuery look like:

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm" action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts">
 <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1" name = "userId" value = "1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox2" name = "userId" value = "2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox3" name = "userId" value = "3" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox4" name = "userId" value = "4" />
<input type="button" id="demo" value = "Demo" />
<input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

**JavaScript+ jQuery**

```
var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

$("#submit").click(function() {
    var allVals = new Array();  
    $("input:checkbox[name=userId]:checked").each(function () {
    allVals.push($(this).val());
    console.log(allVals);

      $.ajax({
              url: url,
              data: {
              userId: allVals
          },
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
        })
        .done(function (json) {
          console.log(json);

        }); 
});
    });
```

In the jQuery Documentation is stated that the "data" option must be an object or a query string. However I have an array. So how can I deal with this situation? I've already tried some things but I can't get it working. How come the first request is correct? (which I actually don't need it) How can I initiate only the XHR Request?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default submit action since you are handling the click event in code.
The document submit that you are seeing is the default form submit action and the Xhr request is your ajax call.

Try handling the form submit event instead

```
<form id="myForm" action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1" name = "userId" value = "1" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox2" name = "userId" value = "2" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox3" name = "userId" value = "3" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox4" name = "userId" value = "4" />
    <input type="button" id="demo" value = "Demo" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

JS

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //This line will prevent the default form submit action
    var allVals = new Array();  
    $("input:checkbox[name=userId]:checked").each(function () {
    allVals.push($(this).val());
    console.log(allVals);

      $.ajax({
              url: url,
              data: {
              userId: allVals
          },
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
        })
        .done(function (json) {
          console.log(json);

        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It's better now but I see now 2 requests:
1: Request URL: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId%5B%5D=3
2: Request URL: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId%5B%5D=3&userId%5B%5D=4

The response to the 2nd request seems to be correct although the request parameters don't seem right. I mean like this:
Request URL: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=3&userId=4

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to set the "traditional" option to true and remove the ajax() from the each() function.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**JavaScript+ jQuery**

```
var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

$("#submit").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault(); //This line will prevent the default form submit action
    allVals = []
    $("input:checkbox[name=userId]:checked").each(function () {
    allVals.push(this.value);
    console.log(allVals);
});
      $.ajax({
          url: url,
          data: {
            userId: allVals
          },
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          traditional: true
        })
        .done(function (json) {
          console.log(json);
        });
});
```